# jquery function always return same

Tags: javascript, jquery

my custom javascript function is working fine. but the problem is it always returning false.

```
function uniqueChk()
{
    var flagV = false;
    jQuery.post("<?=base_url()?>index.php/authentication/chksid",
    { 
        sid: jQuery('#sid').val() 
    }, 
    function( data ) 
    {
        if(data == 'ok')
        {
            jQuery("#sid").removeClass("error");
            jQuery("#er_sid").html("");
            flagV = true;
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery("#sid").addClass("error");
            jQuery("#er_sid").html("This Student ID already in the database. Contact Admin if you have not done first time");
        }
    });
    return flagV;
}
```

If I got value of `data` "ok" its remove the class error from sid but still return `false`.

Comment: post happens after the script uniqueChk has returned.

Comment: data=='ok' is working as i say. it enter the block but can not save true in flagV

Comment: Yes, but you don't appear to understand the asynchronous nature of the `.post` call...

Comment: you can't do it because the ajax request is asynchronous

Comment: Try alerting data and typeof(data) before if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
function uniqueChk()
{
    var flagV = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/authentication/chksid",
        data: { sid: jQuery('#sid').val() },
        success: function(response){
          if(data == 'ok'){
                jQuery("#sid").removeClass("error");
                jQuery("#er_sid").html("");
                flagV = true;
          } else {
                jQuery("#sid").addClass("error");
                jQuery("#er_sid").html("This Student ID already in the database. Contact Admin if you have not done first time");
          }
        },
        async:false
    });
    return flagV;
}
```

By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.

That mean your function doesn't wait for your ajax response to complete.it return it value before your ajax request complete.so make ajax async

REFERENCE

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: +1, the only correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function returning before ajax gets a chance to come back. This is normal behavior for async functionality. Look into $.deferred when then.